# How to abbreviate days of week in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to abbreviate the days of week.

Turn "Monday, Tuesday" to "Mon, Tue".

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <% GlobalConstants::DAYS_OF_WEEK.each_with_index do |day, idx| %>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-row" for="minicourse[days_of_week]">
        <input type="checkbox" id="minicourse_days_of_week" name="minicourse[days_of_week][]" value="<%= idx %>" /><%= day %>
        </label>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: How is GlobalConstants::DAYS_OF_WEEK defined?

Comment: Why not use the `Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES` constant in ruby rather than writing your own?

Comment: @japed I think your comment worth an answer ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko he might have a valid reason not to use that.  Stefan has just posted that anyway, but gone further in doing localised values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For localized values use:

```
I18n.t('date.abbr_day_names')
#=> ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

I18n.locale = :de

I18n.t('date.abbr_day_names')
#=> ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try truncate() ActionView helper.

[see examples here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate)